# Why does booting from Live-USB give me a 'cant find vesamenu.c32' error?

Tags: boot, live-usb

Can't boot Live-USB. Error: 'Cant find vesamenu.c32'. Do I have to Download and install on USB pen again?

Answer (score 1):

Quote from Amedee Van Gasse [ https://launchpad.net/~amedee ] in https://answers.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+question/153014:

> CONFIRMED:
>
> - error message= "Could not find kernel image: vesamenu.c32"
> - error occurs for 11.04 and 10.10 ISO files. 10.04 or below don't have this problem
> - problem also affects all other Ubuntu-based images like Kubuntu, Xubuntu, Mint,...
> - Problem occurs with pendrives created with pendrivelinux's universal usb installer as well as with unetbootin. This leads me to the
>     conclusion that the problem may not be in these tools but in the image
>     itself.
>
> STEPS TO REPRODUCE:
>
> - download 11.04 alternate installer iso from ubuntu.com
> - check download with md5sum
> - create a bootable installer on a pendrive with either universal-usb-installer (Windows) or Unetbootin (Linux)
> - boot with the pendrive
>
> ### WORKAROUND:
>
> 1. **Copy** all files (only files, not directories) from the root (/) of the pendrive to the /syslinux directory of the pendrive.
> 2. **Do NOT** overwrite files that already exist in the /syslinux directory
> 3. **Boot** from the pendrive: no longer any errors.

[...]

Answer (score 1):

doesnt work for me
12.04.1 desktop amd64 and universal usb installer 1.9.1.9

i copied * from /syslinux to /boot then it worked

Answer (score 0):

Edit syslinux.cfg file. Type the path to vesamenu.c32 or menu.c32 file which is located in the isolinux directory.

Comment: Could you be more specofic?