# I am booting Ubuntu 15.10 from a Transcend Jetflash USB drive. getting kernal vesamenu.c32 not found

Tags: windows, usb-drive, 15.10

I am booting Ubuntu 15.10 from my flash drive, and I am getting the error for kernel image vesamenu.c32 (i cant recall the exact error message. The original OS on the C:/ drive is Windows XP.

Can I find the vesamenu.c32 on the internet, download it, and copy it to the correct directory? If so, how many places is it used? Also, if its possible, can you write me a batch (.bat) file for windows to copy it to all the right places? (Or tell me how to write one?)

Thx

Addition to question:

What I am saying is 'is it possible to find the vesamenu.c32 on the internet, download it, and copy it to the appropriate directories? If so, pls tell me where

Answer (score 0):

Try this fix that other people encountering this (same?) problem already were helped by: https://askubuntu.com/a/154293/479652

Comment: All I want right now is to have a link to a download of vesamenu.c32 for Ubuntu 15.10 and the appropriate directories!